# How to send the email from Google Apps Script using GMAIL API?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am trying to automise sending of the Emails from my account using Gmail API in Google Apps Script.

Here is my code:

```
function email_checker() {
  var yourEmailAddress = "###@gmail.com";
  var myEmailAddress = "support@###.com";
  var subject = "testing mail";
  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
  var htmlBody = '<html><body>' + '<h1>HI</h1>' + '</body></html>';

  var message = 'From: Me <' + myEmailAddress + '>\r\n' +
    'To: Me <' + myEmailAddress + '>\r\n' +
    'Subject: ' + subject + '\r\n' +
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n' +
    htmlBody;

  var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(message);
  draftBody = draftBody.replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');

  var params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "message": {
        "raw": draftBody
      }
    })
  };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send", params);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

I am getting the following error: Media type 'application/json' is not supported.

Can anyone please advise on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using the [Gmail advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) that's built into apps script?

Comment: @Diego yes, I need to send email from different address not from the address of the user triggered the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to send an email using Gmail API with UrlFetchApp.
- You have already done the settings for sending the email.

  - Gmail API is enabled.
  - The scopes for sending emails can be included.

#### Modification points:

- From your endtpoint, it is found that the media upload request is used.
- In this case,

  - the request body is required to create with `multipart/alternative`.
  - It is not required to use the base64 encode with the web safe.
  - The content type is required to use `message/rfc822`.
  - The created request body can be directly used for `payload`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function email_checker() {
  var yourEmailAddress = "###@gmail.com";
  var myEmailAddress = "support@###.com";
  var subject = "testing mail";
  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
  var htmlBody = '<html><body>' + '<h1>HI</h1>' + '</body></html>';

  var message = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
    'From: Me <' + myEmailAddress + '>\r\n' +
    'To: Me <' + myEmailAddress + '>\r\n' +
    'Subject: ' + subject + '\r\n' +
    'Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n' +
    '--boundaryboundary\r\n' +
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n' +
    htmlBody + "\r\n\r\n" +
    '--boundaryboundary--';

  var params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "message/rfc822",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: message
  };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send", params);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use the endpoint of `POST https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/send`, please modify your script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var params = {
        method: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        },
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payload: JSON.stringify({
          "message": {
            "raw": draftBody
          }
        })
      };

      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send", params);
      Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var params = {
        method: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        },
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payload: JSON.stringify({"raw": draftBody})
      };

      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send", params);
      Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
    ```
  - In this case, `var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(message); draftBody = draftBody.replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');` can be also modified to `var draftBody = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(message);`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)